# What's the difference between '_io' and 'io'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried the code below. The `f` is of type `_io.TextIOWrapper`, but I cannot find any help info about this type. While there does exsist another similar type `io.TextIOWrapper`.

```
>>> f=open("c:\setup.log","r")
>>> type(f)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> help(_io.TextIOWrapper)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#204>", line 1, in <module>
    help(_io.TextIOWrapper)
NameError: name '_io' is not defined
>>> help(io.TextIOWrapper)
Help on class TextIOWrapper in module io:
```

My questions are:

- If the name `_io` is not defined, how can I use it?
- What's the difference between `_io` and `io` modules?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `_io` module provides the C code that the `io` module uses internally. The source for it can be found [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8da1aa71cd73/Modules/_io). You can actually import both `io` and `_io` separately:

```
>>> import _io
>>> import io
>>> _io
<module 'io' (built-in)>  # The fact that this says io instead of _io is a bug (Issue 18602)
>>> io
<module 'io' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/io.py'>
>>> _io.TextIOWrapper
<type '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```

This pattern (C-code for `modulename` provided in `_modulename`) is actually used for several modules - `multiprocessing`/`_multiprocessing`, `csv`/`_csv`, etc. Basically all cases where a module has a component that's written in C.

Answer (score 8):

`_io` is the C implementation part of the `io` module, `io` the Python part.

From [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names):

> When an extension module written in C or C++ has an accompanying Python module that provides a higher level (e.g. more object oriented) interface, the C/C++ module has a leading underscore (e.g. `_socket`).